# Obtaining a copy of the “attestation d'accueil”

Tags: visa, france

My friends in France obtained and filled out the attestation d'accueil form which I need for my Schengen visa application, however they sent it via the postal service instead of scanning it in and emailing it! I need to apply for my visa ASAP and it is going to take weeks now for the form to arrive (I live in South Africa.)

Is there any way to obtain a copy of it without them having to fill in a whole new document? I think that they sent the original!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible. Your friends should contact the town administration where they live but I have never heard of any provision for that. Unfortunately, it seems they will need to apply for it again.

Note that getting a form and filling it is just the beginning, they need to pay EUR 30 and have it validated by the mayor before sending it to you.